# Why am I getting "ScrollView can only host one direct child" error?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I'm getting the "ScrollView can only host one direct child" error.  I realise that this is often (always?) caused by the ScrollView having more than one child - mulitple answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47962348/scrollview-can-host-only-one-direct-child-with-relativelayout), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316235/scrollview-can-host-only-one-direct-child-exception), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528612/android-scrollview-can-host-only-one-direct-child), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699772/scrollview-can-host-only-one-direct-child) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556612/scrollview-can-host-only-one-direct-child-but-it-has-only-one) on Stack say to wrap the child in a LinearLayout or similar.

However I am sure that I only have one child of my ScrollView.  Please see the below code:

**layout\menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_medium"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/menu_header"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/menu_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <!-- Various LinearLayouts displaying menu items -->
            
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**menu.java**

```
// When one of the menu items is clicked
FragmentTransaction transaction = getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.menu_wrapper, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

**layout\fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_light"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/list_header"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/list_sort"
        layout="@layout/sort" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/inspection_list_header"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/list_loading"
            android:divider="@color/background_medium"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/default_focused"
            android:textSize="18sp">

        </ListView>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/list_loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateOnly="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment.java**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
  this.inspectionListView = rootView;
  return rootView;
}
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
2022-04-25 13:12:59.725 14833-14833/com.*******.*******.mobile E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.*******.*******.mobile, PID: 14833
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
        at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:494)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.addViewToContainer(FragmentStateManager.java:833)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:523)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7211)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple, but I can't work out what.  I've inherited this code and am not an Android developer so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I think you should remove scrollview and add fragment to menu_content linearlayout

Comment: Thanks @Jinal.  When I add my fragment to menu_content it doesn't fill the space.  (Although I'm not removing the ScrollView - how can I do that programmatically?)  Do I need to adjust my width and height somewhere?

Comment: `transaction.replace(R.id.menu_wrapper, fragment);` – That transaction is adding that `Fragment`'s `View` to `menu_wrapper`, which is the  `<ScrollView>` that already has the one `<LinearLayout>` child. Is that really where you meant to put that? It's not going to remove that `<LinearLayout>` first, if that's what you were thinking. Did you maybe mean to transact it into `R.id.menu_content` instead?

Comment: Why r you using a `ScrollView` as Fragment container thats the issue . Not Sure what u want to achieve . If u want fragment to scroll just have ScrollView inside Fragment don't use it as container .

Comment: Ah I see, thanks @Mike.  I think that makes things a little clearer.  Actually I want to replace the entire menu.  Is that possible with a fragment or should I convert the fragment into an activity?

Comment: A `FragmentTransaction` will affect only `View`s that belong to `Fragment`s. It will not remove or replace any other `View`s. Additionally, the `R.id` passed in the `replace()` call is for the `Fragment`s' container, not a specific `View` that you want replaced; the `Fragment`s' `View`s are added/removed/replaced/etc. within that container. Given that, yes, you can probably use `Fragment`s here, but you'd need to change the setup a bit; e.g., make the menu section into its own `Fragment` that's loaded at startup into the shared container, and then transact the others as needed.

Comment: @Mike, ah I see, thanks for the info.  I've read through the documentation, but you've summarised it far better!  I'll have a bit of a think about how to rearrange things to make it fit what I need.  Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Give height and width match_parent to **menu_content**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_medium"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        <include
            android:id="@+id/menu_header"
            layout="@layout/header" />
    

        <!-- This view will be used as fragment container -->

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/menu_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Replace your menu.xml with above code